# Slides within Slider are unresponsive when Jquery parameter set to 5

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have ran into an issue with a Jquery Slider I have grabbed from Code Pen. I have placed 5 images nested in div's which are nested in a section with class slider. The issue is not with the css or html to my knowledge but with the JavaScript.

I have tried changing the jQuery slider parameters.

**jQuery Link**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.js"></script>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.customer-logos').slick({
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 2000,
        arrows: false,
        dots: false,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 768,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 4
            }
        }, {
            breakpoint: 520,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: 3
            }
        }]
    });
});
    </script>
```

**HTML**

```
        <section class="customer-logos slider">
          <div class="slide"><img src="img/image1"></div>
          <div class="slide"><img src="img/image2"></div>
          <div class="slide"><img src="img/image3"></div>
          <div class="slide"><img src="img/image4"></div>
          <div class="slide"><img src="img/image5"></div>
       </section>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.slick-slide {
    margin: 0px 10px;
}

.slick-slide img {
    width: 100%;
}

.slick-slider
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
        touch-action: pan-y;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.slick-list
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.slick-list:focus
{
    outline: none;
}
.slick-list.dragging
{
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

.slick-slider .slick-track,
.slick-slider .slick-list
{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
       -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.slick-track
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
}
.slick-track:before,
.slick-track:after
{
    display: table;
    content: '';
}
.slick-track:after
{
    clear: both;
}
.slick-loading .slick-track
{
    visibility: hidden;
}

.slick-slide
{
    display: none;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-slide
{
    float: right;
}
.slick-slide img
{
    display: block;
}
.slick-slide.slick-loading img
{
    display: none;
}
.slick-slide.dragging img
{
    pointer-events: none;
}
.slick-initialized .slick-slide
{
    display: block;
}
.slick-loading .slick-slide
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.slick-vertical .slick-slide
{
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.slick-arrow.slick-hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

I want 5 images to scroll. Instead a maximum of 4 scrolls works. When I set the JavaScript/jQuery "Slidestoshow" parameter to 5 and above the slider stops working.

Answer (score 0):

You only have 5 slides in list. That is why it is not working when you set number of slides to 5. It is already showing the maximum possible slides. Add one more slide and see the result.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.customer-logos').slick({
        slidesToShow: 5,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 2000,
        arrows: false,
        dots: false,
        pauseOnHover: false,
       
    });
});
```

```css
.slide{
background:blue;
border-radius:10px;
color:#fff;
text-align:center;
padding:20px;
}

.slick-slide {
    margin: 0px 10px;
}

.slick-slide img {
    width: 100%;
}

.slick-slider
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
        touch-action: pan-y;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.slick-list
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.slick-list:focus
{
    outline: none;
}
.slick-list.dragging
{
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

.slick-slider .slick-track,
.slick-slider .slick-list
{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
       -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
         -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.slick-track
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
}
.slick-track:before,
.slick-track:after
{
    display: table;
    content: '';
}
.slick-track:after
{
    clear: both;
}
.slick-loading .slick-track
{
    visibility: hidden;
}

.slick-slide
{
    display: none;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
}
[dir='rtl'] .slick-slide
{
    float: right;
}
.slick-slide img
{
    display: block;
}
.slick-slide.slick-loading img
{
    display: none;
}
.slick-slide.dragging img
{
    pointer-events: none;
}
.slick-initialized .slick-slide
{
    display: block;
}
.slick-loading .slick-slide
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.slick-vertical .slick-slide
{
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
.slick-arrow.slick-hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.js"></script>
 
   <section class="customer-logos slider">
          <div class="slide">1 </div>
          <div class="slide"> 2</div>
          <div class="slide">3 </div>
          <div class="slide"> 4 </div>
          <div class="slide">5 </div>
           <div class="slide">6 </div>
            <div class="slide">7 </div>
             <div class="slide">8</div>
       </section>
```